# Не понимание регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка:

```
preg_match('/[^.]+/', 'hello.bye', $matches);

print_r($matches);

Array
(
    [0] => hello
)
```

Документация:

> . - любой символ, кроме перевода строки.

Так почему же шаблон не видит точки и то что находится за ней, если "любой символ"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[^.]` находит любой символ, отличный от символа `.`, так как `[^...]` образует *исключающий символьный класс*, находящий любой символ, отличный от заданных в классе.

[См. *Символьные классы* в справке по PHP:](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.character-classes.php#regexp.reference.character-classes)

> Символьный класс соответствует одиночному символу обрабатываемой строки, причем сам символ должен содержаться в наборе, определяемым классом. В случае, если первым символом описания класса является '^', логика работы инвертируется: класс соответствует одиночному символу, который не содержится в наборе, определяемым классом. Если символ '^' необходим как член класса, его не следует помещать первым символом в описании класса либо необходимо экранировать при помощи обратного слеша.

Внутри символьных классов `.` не является специальным метасимволом, находящим любой символ, отличный от знака перевода строки (как и многие другие метасимволы). Снова [смотрим справку](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.dot.php):

> Вне символьного класса точка соответствует любому (в том числе и непечатному, бинарному) символу, кроме символа перевода строки '\n' (в обычном режиме). В случае, если используется модификатор [PCRE_DOTALL](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), точка соответствует также символу перевода строки. Обработка метасимвола "точка", никак не связана с метасимволами начала и конца строки, единственное, что у них общего - так это специальное отношение к символу перевода строки. Внутри символьного класса точка не имеет специального значения.

Вам нужен

```
preg_match('/.+/', 'hello.bye', $matches);
```

См. [PHP-демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/gRTomY).

[Шаблон `.+`](https://regex101.com/r/YfQ0Bi/1) найдет 1 и более символов, отличных от знаков перехода на новую строку.

Comment: То есть символ ^  служит для отличия? Но в документации написано что он означает Начало данных.

Comment: Это уже из другой оперы, `^` в начале символьного класса задаёт исключающий символьный класс. `^` вне символьных классов находит начало строки.